# How to get Date from TimeStamp in java

Tags: java, mysql, date, timestamp

I am trying to read a timestamp I have in my database mysql and save it to a Date variable in java.

I want it with this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (24 hour format)

In my database I have a timestamp with that format but each time I try to get as timestamp I read 2014 and if I read it as Date with getDate()... I get "ago 16, 2014"

Comment: What's with some code and database definitions? Then we could elaborate a little better...

Comment: getDate() doesn't work with Mysql.

Comment: What language is “ago”?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want. Do you want to get a java.sql.Timestamp instance or do you want to get the timestamp as string with the mentioned pattern?

Maybe that helps:

```
ResultSet rs = ...
Timestamp t = rs.getTimestamp(...);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String str = sdf.format(t);
```

Comment: I am trying your answer right now but I am getting some king of problem when printing hour. If I put hh I get 00 if I put HH I get 12, but my hour for example is 19:... always get or 00 of 12

Comment: HH means Hour in Day (0-23) and hh means Hour in am/pm. It looks like your timestamp value has no hour. Can you tell the exact timestamp value (t.getTime())

Comment: It is a server and I cannot print it by console but in database I have: 2014-07-07 19:30:00 as timeStamp

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the timestamp from the DB
java.sql.Timestamp yourTimestamp = youNameItGetTimestamp();

// Create the corresponding Date object
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(yourTimestamp.getTime());

// show in a string
java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
java.lang.String printableDate = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println("here you have it: <" + printableDate + ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct but use troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Instead use java.time classes.

## Conversion

New methods have been added to the old classes to facilitate conversion such as [`java.sql.Timestamp::toInstant()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … ) ;
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Its `toString` method generates a String in one of the standard ISO 8601 formats.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2011-12-03T10:15:30Z

You could replace the `T` with a SPACE and delete the `Z` to get your format.

```
output = output.replace( "T" , " ").replace( "Z" , "" ) ;
```

> 2011-12-03 10:15:30

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to see the same moment but through the lens of a particular time zone, generate a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZonedId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

Define a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object. Or use [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) and replace the `T` with a SPACE.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace( "T" , " " );
```

> 2011-12-03 05:15:30

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

have you tried some thing like this :

java.sql.Date timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp( object.getDate() );

also this link may help you :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score -2):

What's the type of your field? Is it a string/varchar? How about using SimpleDateFormat?

i.e.

```
final Date myDate = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_STRING).parse(value);
```

See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for more details.

BTW: A litte code and database definition would have been nice...